# how setTimeout act like setInterval in the clock code below even setTimeout execute one time only?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, timing

please look to my code to know the problem !!!

this is the problem ?

1. why they used setTimeout and it execute 1 time only , and the clock need some method execute continuously like setInterval ? even setInterval work in this code , but my problem is setTimeout execute 1 time only why it's work here in this code ?
2. why it's 500 milliseconds while 1 second = 1000 ?

   help me please

i changed `setTimeout` with `setInterval` and both worked this make the problem bigger how both do the same thing in this example even they are not the same ?

```
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i}; // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}
```

Comment: <script>

function startTime() {
  var today = new Date();
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var s = today.getSeconds();
  m = checkTime(m);
  s = checkTime(s);
  document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
  h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
  var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
  return i;
}

</script>

Comment: please add the code to the QUESTION where you can format it, not as a comment

Comment: but it's clear that `setTimeout(startTime, 500)` calls `startTime` which calls `setTimeout(startTime, 500)` which calls `startTime` ... etc etc ... however, using `setInterval` in place of `setTimeout` is the **wrong** thing to do, since you'll be adding more and more intervals, so the code would run multiple times every half second, until eventually, the page will probably become unresponsive

Comment: "please look to my code to know the problem !!!" okay; but where ???

Comment: Jaromanda X  : really thank you mate  You are awesome  now i understand , but just small thing u said setInterval wrong it run the code multiple times "i understand this", but also setTimeout which calls start time and etc , will also call the function multiple times and will act like setInterval  and call start time every ,5 sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

1. It acts like `setInterval` because it calls himself every 0.5 sec recursively: `setTimeout(startTime, 500)`
2. You are right, it runs every ~0.5 sec and not 1 sec as areal clock. Maybe they thought that the logic in `startTime` will take 0.5 sec so together it will take 1 sec, but, obviously it's not true.